Error using mcp2atm function for robust pairwise comparisons - undefined columns selected
I used a robust two-way ANOVA using the WRS2 package (R v.4.4.1), using the following code as suggested by Mair and Wilcox (2020) - the full dataset is on the bottom of this message:
library(WRS2) 

khg<-read.table("khg.txt", h = T, dec = ".", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=T, na.strings = "NA")

t2way(fr ~ t * as.factor(i), data = khg)


This worked fine, so it returned:
Call:
t2way(formula = fr ~ t * as.factor(i), data = khg)

                   value p.value
t               133.0420   0.001
as.factor(i)   3317.8926   0.001
t:as.factor(i)  150.6804   0.001

When I run the pairwise comparison using mcp2atm(), I get:
mcp2atm(fr ~ t * as.factor(i), data = khg)

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, variable.names(mf)) : 
  undefined columns selected

So, it is basically the same code for the same dataframe, but now I get an error message. I tried to look at the pairwiseRobustTest() function from the package 'rcompanion' but it is now [Defunct!] as in the last version of 'rcompanion', so I am afraid I am running out of options...
Any thoughts on how to circumvent this problem?
Thanks in advance!
The data is as follows:
i   t   c   fr
0   Warm    1   0
50  Warm    1   2
100 Warm    1   6
150 Warm    1   16
200 Warm    1   20
250 Warm    1   24
300 Warm    1   26
350 Warm    1   28
400 Warm    1   32
450 Warm    1   34
500 Warm    1   36
550 Warm    1   38
600 Warm    1   40
650 Warm    1   42
700 Warm    1   44
750 Warm    1   46
800 Warm    1   46
850 Warm    1   48
900 Warm    1   48
950 Warm    1   46
1000    Warm    1   42
1050    Warm    1   32
1100    Warm    1   42
1150    Warm    1   38
1200    Warm    1   28
1250    Warm    1   28
1300    Warm    1   28
0   Warm    2   0
50  Warm    2   0
100 Warm    2   0
150 Warm    2   0
200 Warm    2   0
250 Warm    2   2
300 Warm    2   6
350 Warm    2   12
400 Warm    2   20
450 Warm    2   30
500 Warm    2   38
550 Warm    2   46
600 Warm    2   54
650 Warm    2   60
700 Warm    2   64
750 Warm    2   68
800 Warm    2   72
850 Warm    2   76
900 Warm    2   78
950 Warm    2   80
1000    Warm    2   82
1050    Warm    2   84
1100    Warm    2   88
1150    Warm    2   90
1200    Warm    2   94
1250    Warm    2   94
1300    Warm    2   96
0   Warm    3   0
50  Warm    3   6
100 Warm    3   16
150 Warm    3   22
200 Warm    3   28
250 Warm    3   32
300 Warm    3   38
350 Warm    3   42
400 Warm    3   46
450 Warm    3   50
500 Warm    3   54
550 Warm    3   58
600 Warm    3   62
650 Warm    3   66
700 Warm    3   68
750 Warm    3   72
800 Warm    3   76
850 Warm    3   78
900 Warm    3   82
950 Warm    3   84
1000    Warm    3   86
1050    Warm    3   88
1100    Warm    3   92
1150    Warm    3   94
1200    Warm    3   96
1250    Warm    3   98
1300    Warm    3   102
0   Warm    4   6
50  Warm    4   10
100 Warm    4   12
150 Warm    4   14
200 Warm    4   16
250 Warm    4   20
300 Warm    4   22
350 Warm    4   26
400 Warm    4   26
450 Warm    4   30
500 Warm    4   32
550 Warm    4   34
600 Warm    4   36
650 Warm    4   38
700 Warm    4   40
750 Warm    4   42
800 Warm    4   46
850 Warm    4   48
900 Warm    4   50
950 Warm    4   50
1000    Warm    4   52
1050    Warm    4   56
1100    Warm    4   58
1150    Warm    4   58
1200    Warm    4   62
1250    Warm    4   62
1300    Warm    4   66
0   Warm    5   0
50  Warm    5   0
100 Warm    5   8
150 Warm    5   16
200 Warm    5   20
250 Warm    5   26
300 Warm    5   30
350 Warm    5   34
400 Warm    5   38
450 Warm    5   42
500 Warm    5   46
550 Warm    5   52
600 Warm    5   54
650 Warm    5   58
700 Warm    5   60
750 Warm    5   64
800 Warm    5   68
850 Warm    5   70
900 Warm    5   72
950 Warm    5   76
1000    Warm    5   76
1050    Warm    5   78
1100    Warm    5   82
1150    Warm    5   84
1200    Warm    5   82
1250    Warm    5   74
1300    Warm    5   72
0   Warm    6   0
50  Warm    6   2
100 Warm    6   10
150 Warm    6   16
200 Warm    6   22
250 Warm    6   26
300 Warm    6   34
350 Warm    6   34
400 Warm    6   38
450 Warm    6   42
500 Warm    6   44
550 Warm    6   48
600 Warm    6   52
650 Warm    6   54
700 Warm    6   58
750 Warm    6   60
800 Warm    6   62
850 Warm    6   66
900 Warm    6   68
950 Warm    6   70
1000    Warm    6   72
1050    Warm    6   76
1100    Warm    6   78
1150    Warm    6   80
1200    Warm    6   82
1250    Warm    6   84
1300    Warm    6   84
0   Warm    7   0
50  Warm    7   2
100 Warm    7   10
150 Warm    7   16
200 Warm    7   22
250 Warm    7   30
300 Warm    7   36
350 Warm    7   40
400 Warm    7   46
450 Warm    7   54
500 Warm    7   58
550 Warm    7   64
600 Warm    7   68
650 Warm    7   74
700 Warm    7   80
750 Warm    7   84
800 Warm    7   90
850 Warm    7   94
900 Warm    7   100
950 Warm    7   104
1000    Warm    7   108
1050    Warm    7   112
1100    Warm    7   116
1150    Warm    7   120
1200    Warm    7   122
1250    Warm    7   126
1300    Warm    7   128
0   Warm    8   0
50  Warm    8   0
100 Warm    8   0
150 Warm    8   0
200 Warm    8   0
250 Warm    8   0
300 Warm    8   0
350 Warm    8   0
400 Warm    8   0
450 Warm    8   0
500 Warm    8   0
550 Warm    8   0
600 Warm    8   0
650 Warm    8   0
700 Warm    8   0
750 Warm    8   0
800 Warm    8   0
850 Warm    8   2
900 Warm    8   6
950 Warm    8   10
1000    Warm    8   14
1050    Warm    8   20
1100    Warm    8   24
1150    Warm    8   28
1200    Warm    8   32
1250    Warm    8   36
1300    Warm    8   42
0   Warm    9   0
50  Warm    9   0
100 Warm    9   0
150 Warm    9   4
200 Warm    9   10
250 Warm    9   14
300 Warm    9   18
350 Warm    9   22
400 Warm    9   26
450 Warm    9   30
500 Warm    9   32
550 Warm    9   34
600 Warm    9   38
650 Warm    9   40
700 Warm    9   44
750 Warm    9   46
800 Warm    9   48
850 Warm    9   50
900 Warm    9   54
950 Warm    9   56
1000    Warm    9   58
1050    Warm    9   60
1100    Warm    9   62
1150    Warm    9   64
1200    Warm    9   64
1250    Warm    9   66
1300    Warm    9   68
0   Warm    10  0
50  Warm    10  0
100 Warm    10  0
150 Warm    10  0
200 Warm    10  0
250 Warm    10  0
300 Warm    10  4
350 Warm    10  12
400 Warm    10  20
450 Warm    10  28
500 Warm    10  34
550 Warm    10  38
600 Warm    10  44
650 Warm    10  48
700 Warm    10  52
750 Warm    10  56
800 Warm    10  60
850 Warm    10  64
900 Warm    10  64
950 Warm    10  68
1000    Warm    10  70
1050    Warm    10  74
1100    Warm    10  76
1150    Warm    10  76
1200    Warm    10  78
1250    Warm    10  80
1300    Warm    10  80
0   Warm    11  0
50  Warm    11  0
100 Warm    11  0
150 Warm    11  6
200 Warm    11  16
250 Warm    11  26
300 Warm    11  34
350 Warm    11  42
400 Warm    11  48
450 Warm    11  56
500 Warm    11  62
550 Warm    11  68
600 Warm    11  74
650 Warm    11  80
700 Warm    11  86
750 Warm    11  92
800 Warm    11  96
850 Warm    11  102
900 Warm    11  108
950 Warm    11  112
1000    Warm    11  116
1050    Warm    11  122
1100    Warm    11  124
1150    Warm    11  130
1200    Warm    11  134
1250    Warm    11  138
1300    Warm    11  142
0   Warm    12  0
50  Warm    12  0
100 Warm    12  0
150 Warm    12  0
200 Warm    12  0
250 Warm    12  6
300 Warm    12  12
350 Warm    12  16
400 Warm    12  20
450 Warm    12  24
500 Warm    12  26
550 Warm    12  30
600 Warm    12  32
650 Warm    12  36
700 Warm    12  38
750 Warm    12  42
800 Warm    12  44
850 Warm    12  46
900 Warm    12  50
950 Warm    12  52
1000    Warm    12  54
1050    Warm    12  56
1100    Warm    12  58
1150    Warm    12  62
1200    Warm    12  64
1250    Warm    12  66
1300    Warm    12  70
0   Warm    13  0
50  Warm    13  14
100 Warm    13  26
150 Warm    13  38
200 Warm    13  46
250 Warm    13  54
300 Warm    13  62
350 Warm    13  68
400 Warm    13  74
450 Warm    13  76
500 Warm    13  82
550 Warm    13  82
600 Warm    13  88
650 Warm    13  92
700 Warm    13  94
750 Warm    13  92
800 Warm    13  92
850 Warm    13  100
900 Warm    13  108
950 Warm    13  104
1000    Warm    13  102
1050    Warm    13  96
1100    Warm    13  56
1150    Warm    13  40
1200    Warm    13  38
1250    Warm    13  34
1300    Warm    13  30
0   Warm    14  0
50  Warm    14  8
100 Warm    14  14
150 Warm    14  18
200 Warm    14  20
250 Warm    14  24
300 Warm    14  26
350 Warm    14  30
400 Warm    14  32
450 Warm    14  34
500 Warm    14  38
550 Warm    14  40
600 Warm    14  42
650 Warm    14  44
700 Warm    14  46
750 Warm    14  48
800 Warm    14  50
850 Warm    14  52
900 Warm    14  54
950 Warm    14  54
1000    Warm    14  56
1050    Warm    14  58
1100    Warm    14  60
1150    Warm    14  60
1200    Warm    14  62
1250    Warm    14  64
1300    Warm    14  66
0   Warm    15  10
50  Warm    15  42
100 Warm    15  112
150 Warm    15  178
200 Warm    15  204
250 Warm    15  220
300 Warm    15  234
350 Warm    15  244
400 Warm    15  252
450 Warm    15  260
500 Warm    15  264
550 Warm    15  268
600 Warm    15  268
650 Warm    15  268
700 Warm    15  266
750 Warm    15  256
800 Warm    15  188
850 Warm    15  136
900 Warm    15  100
950 Warm    15  80
1000    Warm    15  66
1050    Warm    15  64
1100    Warm    15  42
1150    Warm    15  38
1200    Warm    15  32
1250    Warm    15  28
1300    Warm    15  24
0   Warm    16  0
50  Warm    16  0
100 Warm    16  0
150 Warm    16  10
200 Warm    16  18
250 Warm    16  24
300 Warm    16  32
350 Warm    16  38
400 Warm    16  44
450 Warm    16  48
500 Warm    16  54
550 Warm    16  58
600 Warm    16  62
650 Warm    16  66
700 Warm    16  70
750 Warm    16  74
800 Warm    16  78
850 Warm    16  80
900 Warm    16  84
950 Warm    16  86
1000    Warm    16  90
1050    Warm    16  92
1100    Warm    16  96
1150    Warm    16  98
1200    Warm    16  102
1250    Warm    16  102
1300    Warm    16  104
0   Warm    17  0
50  Warm    17  0
100 Warm    17  0
150 Warm    17  0
200 Warm    17  0
250 Warm    17  0
300 Warm    17  4
350 Warm    17  10
400 Warm    17  14
450 Warm    17  20
500 Warm    17  24
550 Warm    17  28
600 Warm    17  32
650 Warm    17  36
700 Warm    17  40
750 Warm    17  44
800 Warm    17  46
850 Warm    17  50
900 Warm    17  54
950 Warm    17  56
1000    Warm    17  60
1050    Warm    17  62
1100    Warm    17  64
1150    Warm    17  68
1200    Warm    17  70
1250    Warm    17  74
1300    Warm    17  76
0   Warm    18  0
50  Warm    18  0
100 Warm    18  0
150 Warm    18  0
200 Warm    18  0
250 Warm    18  0
300 Warm    18  0
350 Warm    18  0
400 Warm    18  0
450 Warm    18  0
500 Warm    18  0
550 Warm    18  0
600 Warm    18  0
650 Warm    18  0
700 Warm    18  4
750 Warm    18  10
800 Warm    18  14
850 Warm    18  18
900 Warm    18  22
950 Warm    18  24
1000    Warm    18  28
1050    Warm    18  30
1100    Warm    18  32
1150    Warm    18  34
1200    Warm    18  36
1250    Warm    18  38
1300    Warm    18  42
0   Warm    19  0
50  Warm    19  14
100 Warm    19  26
150 Warm    19  38
200 Warm    19  46
250 Warm    19  54
300 Warm    19  62
350 Warm    19  68
400 Warm    19  74
450 Warm    19  76
500 Warm    19  82
550 Warm    19  82
600 Warm    19  88
650 Warm    19  92
700 Warm    19  94
750 Warm    19  92
800 Warm    19  92
850 Warm    19  100
900 Warm    19  108
950 Warm    19  104
1000    Warm    19  102
1050    Warm    19  96
1100    Warm    19  56
1150    Warm    19  40
1200    Warm    19  38
1250    Warm    19  34
1300    Warm    19  30
0   Warm    20  12
50  Warm    20  22
100 Warm    20  28
150 Warm    20  34
200 Warm    20  42
250 Warm    20  48
300 Warm    20  54
350 Warm    20  60
400 Warm    20  66
450 Warm    20  70
500 Warm    20  74
550 Warm    20  78
600 Warm    20  82
650 Warm    20  88
700 Warm    20  92
750 Warm    20  96
800 Warm    20  98
850 Warm    20  102
900 Warm    20  104
950 Warm    20  106
1000    Warm    20  110
1050    Warm    20  112
1100    Warm    20  114
1150    Warm    20  116
1200    Warm    20  118
1250    Warm    20  120
1300    Warm    20  120
0   Warm    21  0
50  Warm    21  0
100 Warm    21  14
150 Warm    21  26
200 Warm    21  32
250 Warm    21  38
300 Warm    21  44
350 Warm    21  48
400 Warm    21  52
450 Warm    21  54
500 Warm    21  58
550 Warm    21  60
600 Warm    21  62
650 Warm    21  66
700 Warm    21  68
750 Warm    21  70
800 Warm    21  72
850 Warm    21  74
900 Warm    21  76
950 Warm    21  76
1000    Warm    21  78
1050    Warm    21  80
1100    Warm    21  80
1150    Warm    21  80
1200    Warm    21  82
1250    Warm    21  82
1300    Warm    21  82
0   Warm    22  0
50  Warm    22  2
100 Warm    22  12
150 Warm    22  16
200 Warm    22  22
250 Warm    22  26
300 Warm    22  30
350 Warm    22  32
400 Warm    22  36
450 Warm    22  38
500 Warm    22  40
550 Warm    22  44
600 Warm    22  46
650 Warm    22  48
700 Warm    22  50
750 Warm    22  50
800 Warm    22  52
850 Warm    22  54
900 Warm    22  56
950 Warm    22  58
1000    Warm    22  58
1050    Warm    22  60
1100    Warm    22  60
1150    Warm    22  62
1200    Warm    22  64
1250    Warm    22  64
1300    Warm    22  66
0   Warm    23  0
50  Warm    23  0
100 Warm    23  0
150 Warm    23  6
200 Warm    23  18
250 Warm    23  26
300 Warm    23  36
350 Warm    23  44
400 Warm    23  48
450 Warm    23  58
500 Warm    23  64
550 Warm    23  72
600 Warm    23  76
650 Warm    23  82
700 Warm    23  88
750 Warm    23  92
800 Warm    23  96
850 Warm    23  102
900 Warm    23  108
950 Warm    23  114
1000    Warm    23  118
1050    Warm    23  124
1100    Warm    23  128
1150    Warm    23  132
1200    Warm    23  136
1250    Warm    23  140
1300    Warm    23  146
0   Warm    24  0
50  Warm    24  0
100 Warm    24  0
150 Warm    24  0
200 Warm    24  0
250 Warm    24  0
300 Warm    24  10
350 Warm    24  16
400 Warm    24  22
450 Warm    24  28
500 Warm    24  32
550 Warm    24  36
600 Warm    24  40
650 Warm    24  44
700 Warm    24  48
750 Warm    24  50
800 Warm    24  54
850 Warm    24  56
900 Warm    24  58
950 Warm    24  62
1000    Warm    24  64
1050    Warm    24  66
1100    Warm    24  68
1150    Warm    24  70
1200    Warm    24  72
1250    Warm    24  74
1300    Warm    24  76
0   Warm    25  0
50  Warm    25  6
100 Warm    25  10
150 Warm    25  14
200 Warm    25  18
250 Warm    25  20
300 Warm    25  24
350 Warm    25  26
400 Warm    25  28
450 Warm    25  30
500 Warm    25  34
550 Warm    25  36
600 Warm    25  36
650 Warm    25  40
700 Warm    25  42
750 Warm    25  42
800 Warm    25  46
850 Warm    25  46
900 Warm    25  48
950 Warm    25  50
1000    Warm    25  50
1050    Warm    25  52
1100    Warm    25  54
1150    Warm    25  56
1200    Warm    25  56
1250    Warm    25  58
1300    Warm    25  60
0   Warm    26  10
50  Warm    26  18
100 Warm    26  28
150 Warm    26  34
200 Warm    26  44
250 Warm    26  52
300 Warm    26  60
350 Warm    26  68
400 Warm    26  76
450 Warm    26  82
500 Warm    26  90
550 Warm    26  98
600 Warm    26  102
650 Warm    26  108
700 Warm    26  112
750 Warm    26  116
800 Warm    26  120
850 Warm    26  122
900 Warm    26  126
950 Warm    26  126
1000    Warm    26  130
1050    Warm    26  132
1100    Warm    26  134
1150    Warm    26  136
1200    Warm    26  138
1250    Warm    26  138
1300    Warm    26  140
0   Warm    27  0
50  Warm    27  0
100 Warm    27  4
150 Warm    27  14
200 Warm    27  24
250 Warm    27  32
300 Warm    27  38
350 Warm    27  46
400 Warm    27  48
450 Warm    27  54
500 Warm    27  62
550 Warm    27  66
600 Warm    27  72
650 Warm    27  78
700 Warm    27  82
750 Warm    27  86
800 Warm    27  92
850 Warm    27  96
900 Warm    27  100
950 Warm    27  106
1000    Warm    27  108
1050    Warm    27  112
1100    Warm    27  116
1150    Warm    27  120
1200    Warm    27  124
1250    Warm    27  128
1300    Warm    27  132
0   Warm    28  16
50  Warm    28  28
100 Warm    28  42
150 Warm    28  56
200 Warm    28  70
250 Warm    28  82
300 Warm    28  94
350 Warm    28  106
400 Warm    28  114
450 Warm    28  126
500 Warm    28  130
550 Warm    28  138
600 Warm    28  144
650 Warm    28  150
700 Warm    28  154
750 Warm    28  156
800 Warm    28  158
850 Warm    28  164
900 Warm    28  162
950 Warm    28  170
1000    Warm    28  168
1050    Warm    28  170
1100    Warm    28  172
1150    Warm    28  172
1200    Warm    28  172
1250    Warm    28  172
1300    Warm    28  170
0   Warm    29  10
50  Warm    29  16
100 Warm    29  26
150 Warm    29  30
200 Warm    29  38
250 Warm    29  46
300 Warm    29  50
350 Warm    29  58
400 Warm    29  64
450 Warm    29  70
500 Warm    29  76
550 Warm    29  82
600 Warm    29  88
650 Warm    29  92
700 Warm    29  98
750 Warm    29  102
800 Warm    29  106
850 Warm    29  110
900 Warm    29  116
950 Warm    29  120
1000    Warm    29  122
1050    Warm    29  126
1100    Warm    29  128
1150    Warm    29  128
1200    Warm    29  132
1250    Warm    29  132
1300    Warm    29  132
0   Warm    30  0
50  Warm    30  6
100 Warm    30  12
150 Warm    30  16
200 Warm    30  20
250 Warm    30  22
300 Warm    30  26
350 Warm    30  28
400 Warm    30  32
450 Warm    30  34
500 Warm    30  36
550 Warm    30  38
600 Warm    30  42
650 Warm    30  44
700 Warm    30  46
750 Warm    30  48
800 Warm    30  50
850 Warm    30  52
900 Warm    30  56
950 Warm    30  58
1000    Warm    30  60
1050    Warm    30  62
1100    Warm    30  64
1150    Warm    30  66
1200    Warm    30  68
1250    Warm    30  72
1300    Warm    30  74
0   Warm    31  0
50  Warm    31  0
100 Warm    31  0
150 Warm    31  0
200 Warm    31  0
250 Warm    31  10
300 Warm    31  22
350 Warm    31  30
400 Warm    31  38
450 Warm    31  46
500 Warm    31  52
550 Warm    31  60
600 Warm    31  64
650 Warm    31  72
700 Warm    31  76
750 Warm    31  82
800 Warm    31  86
850 Warm    31  92
900 Warm    31  96
950 Warm    31  100
1000    Warm    31  106
1050    Warm    31  110
1100    Warm    31  114
1150    Warm    31  116
1200    Warm    31  122
1250    Warm    31  124
1300    Warm    31  126
0   Warm    32  8
50  Warm    32  16
100 Warm    32  24
150 Warm    32  32
200 Warm    32  38
250 Warm    32  46
300 Warm    32  52
350 Warm    32  58
400 Warm    32  62
450 Warm    32  68
500 Warm    32  72
550 Warm    32  76
600 Warm    32  80
650 Warm    32  84
700 Warm    32  88
750 Warm    32  90
800 Warm    32  94
850 Warm    32  94
900 Warm    32  96
950 Warm    32  98
1000    Warm    32  100
1050    Warm    32  102
1100    Warm    32  100
1150    Warm    32  100
1200    Warm    32  96
1250    Warm    32  76
1300    Warm    32  62
0   Warm    33  0
50  Warm    33  0
100 Warm    33  4
150 Warm    33  14
200 Warm    33  18
250 Warm    33  24
300 Warm    33  30
350 Warm    33  36
400 Warm    33  40
450 Warm    33  44
500 Warm    33  50
550 Warm    33  54
600 Warm    33  58
650 Warm    33  60
700 Warm    33  66
750 Warm    33  70
800 Warm    33  74
850 Warm    33  78
900 Warm    33  80
950 Warm    33  84
1000    Warm    33  88
1050    Warm    33  92
1100    Warm    33  96
1150    Warm    33  98
1200    Warm    33  102
1250    Warm    33  104
1300    Warm    33  108
0   Cold    34  0
50  Cold    34  0
100 Cold    34  0
150 Cold    34  0
200 Cold    34  0
250 Cold    34  0
300 Cold    34  6
350 Cold    34  10
400 Cold    34  12
450 Cold    34  16
500 Cold    34  18
550 Cold    34  20
600 Cold    34  22
650 Cold    34  24
700 Cold    34  26
750 Cold    34  28
800 Cold    34  30
850 Cold    34  32
900 Cold    34  34
950 Cold    34  36
1000    Cold    34  38
1050    Cold    34  38
1100    Cold    34  40
1150    Cold    34  42
1200    Cold    34  44
1250    Cold    34  46
1300    Cold    34  46
0   Cold    35  0
50  Cold    35  0
100 Cold    35  4
150 Cold    35  10
200 Cold    35  16
250 Cold    35  20
300 Cold    35  24
350 Cold    35  28
400 Cold    35  32
450 Cold    35  34
500 Cold    35  38
550 Cold    35  42
600 Cold    35  44
650 Cold    35  48
700 Cold    35  50
750 Cold    35  54
800 Cold    35  56
850 Cold    35  58
900 Cold    35  60
950 Cold    35  62
1000    Cold    35  66
1050    Cold    35  68
1100    Cold    35  68
1150    Cold    35  72
1200    Cold    35  72
1250    Cold    35  74
1300    Cold    35  76
0   Cold    36  0
50  Cold    36  0
100 Cold    36  6
150 Cold    36  8
200 Cold    36  8
250 Cold    36  8
300 Cold    36  10
350 Cold    36  10
400 Cold    36  10
450 Cold    36  12
500 Cold    36  12
550 Cold    36  12
600 Cold    36  14
650 Cold    36  14
700 Cold    36  14
750 Cold    36  14
800 Cold    36  16
850 Cold    36  16
900 Cold    36  16
950 Cold    36  16
1000    Cold    36  16
1050    Cold    36  16
1100    Cold    36  16
1150    Cold    36  16
1200    Cold    36  16
1250    Cold    36  14
1300    Cold    36  16
0   Cold    37  0
50  Cold    37  0
100 Cold    37  0
150 Cold    37  4
200 Cold    37  16
250 Cold    37  20
300 Cold    37  24
350 Cold    37  26
400 Cold    37  30
450 Cold    37  36
500 Cold    37  38
550 Cold    37  42
600 Cold    37  44
650 Cold    37  46
700 Cold    37  50
750 Cold    37  50
800 Cold    37  52
850 Cold    37  54
900 Cold    37  42
950 Cold    37  40
1000    Cold    37  36
1050    Cold    37  38
1100    Cold    37  28
1150    Cold    37  30
1200    Cold    37  38
1250    Cold    37  32
1300    Cold    37  28
0   Cold    38  0
50  Cold    38  0
100 Cold    38  0
150 Cold    38  0
200 Cold    38  0
250 Cold    38  0
300 Cold    38  0
350 Cold    38  0
400 Cold    38  0
450 Cold    38  0
500 Cold    38  2
550 Cold    38  10
600 Cold    38  16
650 Cold    38  20
700 Cold    38  24
750 Cold    38  26
800 Cold    38  28
850 Cold    38  32
900 Cold    38  34
950 Cold    38  36
1000    Cold    38  40
1050    Cold    38  42
1100    Cold    38  44
1150    Cold    38  46
1200    Cold    38  48
1250    Cold    38  50
1300    Cold    38  54
0   Cold    39  8
50  Cold    39  12
100 Cold    39  24
150 Cold    39  32
200 Cold    39  44
250 Cold    39  54
300 Cold    39  72
350 Cold    39  80
400 Cold    39  60
450 Cold    39  100
500 Cold    39  64
550 Cold    39  54
600 Cold    39  52
650 Cold    39  38
700 Cold    39  34
750 Cold    39  36
800 Cold    39  34
850 Cold    39  28
900 Cold    39  24
950 Cold    39  22
1000    Cold    39  20
1050    Cold    39  24
1100    Cold    39  22
1150    Cold    39  22
1200    Cold    39  24
1250    Cold    39  26
1300    Cold    39  20
0   Cold    40  0
50  Cold    40  0
100 Cold    40  2
150 Cold    40  10
200 Cold    40  16
250 Cold    40  20
300 Cold    40  24
350 Cold    40  28
400 Cold    40  32
450 Cold    40  36
500 Cold    40  38
550 Cold    40  42
600 Cold    40  44
650 Cold    40  44
700 Cold    40  44
750 Cold    40  36
800 Cold    40  28
850 Cold    40  32
900 Cold    40  30
950 Cold    40  32
1000    Cold    40  26
1050    Cold    40  18
1100    Cold    40  28
1150    Cold    40  26
1200    Cold    40  26
1250    Cold    40  24
1300    Cold    40  22
0   Cold    41  0
50  Cold    41  0
100 Cold    41  4
150 Cold    41  14
200 Cold    41  20
250 Cold    41  26
300 Cold    41  30
350 Cold    41  36
400 Cold    41  40
450 Cold    41  42
500 Cold    41  46
550 Cold    41  50
600 Cold    41  54
650 Cold    41  58
700 Cold    41  60
750 Cold    41  64
800 Cold    41  68
850 Cold    41  70
900 Cold    41  74
950 Cold    41  76
1000    Cold    41  80
1050    Cold    41  82
1100    Cold    41  84
1150    Cold    41  88
1200    Cold    41  90
1250    Cold    41  92
1300    Cold    41  96
0   Cold    42  0
50  Cold    42  12
100 Cold    42  26
150 Cold    42  38
200 Cold    42  46
250 Cold    42  54
300 Cold    42  62
350 Cold    42  70
400 Cold    42  76
450 Cold    42  84
500 Cold    42  92
550 Cold    42  98
600 Cold    42  106
650 Cold    42  110
700 Cold    42  118
750 Cold    42  124
800 Cold    42  130
850 Cold    42  136
900 Cold    42  140
950 Cold    42  144
1000    Cold    42  152
1050    Cold    42  156
1100    Cold    42  162
1150    Cold    42  166
1200    Cold    42  170
1250    Cold    42  174
1300    Cold    42  180
0   Cold    43  0
50  Cold    43  0
100 Cold    43  0
150 Cold    43  0
200 Cold    43  0
250 Cold    43  0
300 Cold    43  0
350 Cold    43  6
400 Cold    43  8
450 Cold    43  14
500 Cold    43  18
550 Cold    43  22
600 Cold    43  24
650 Cold    43  28
700 Cold    43  30
750 Cold    43  34
800 Cold    43  36
850 Cold    43  38
900 Cold    43  40
950 Cold    43  42
1000    Cold    43  44
1050    Cold    43  46
1100    Cold    43  48
1150    Cold    43  50
1200    Cold    43  52
1250    Cold    43  54
1300    Cold    43  56
0   Cold    44  0
50  Cold    44  0
100 Cold    44  0
150 Cold    44  8
200 Cold    44  16
250 Cold    44  24
300 Cold    44  30
350 Cold    44  36
400 Cold    44  40
450 Cold    44  46
500 Cold    44  52
550 Cold    44  58
600 Cold    44  62
650 Cold    44  66
700 Cold    44  70
750 Cold    44  74
800 Cold    44  82
850 Cold    44  84
900 Cold    44  94
950 Cold    44  102
1000    Cold    44  106
1050    Cold    44  112
1100    Cold    44  116
1150    Cold    44  122
1200    Cold    44  120
1250    Cold    44  124
1300    Cold    44  130
0   Cold    45  0
50  Cold    45  0
100 Cold    45  0
150 Cold    45  0
200 Cold    45  8
250 Cold    45  14
300 Cold    45  20
350 Cold    45  24
400 Cold    45  30
450 Cold    45  34
500 Cold    45  40
550 Cold    45  44
600 Cold    45  48
650 Cold    45  52
700 Cold    45  56
750 Cold    45  60
800 Cold    45  64
850 Cold    45  70
900 Cold    45  74
950 Cold    45  78
1000    Cold    45  82
1050    Cold    45  86
1100    Cold    45  92
1150    Cold    45  94
1200    Cold    45  98
1250    Cold    45  102
1300    Cold    45  106
0   Cold    46  0
50  Cold    46  0
100 Cold    46  0
150 Cold    46  0
200 Cold    46  0
250 Cold    46  0
300 Cold    46  0
350 Cold    46  0
400 Cold    46  0
450 Cold    46  0
500 Cold    46  0
550 Cold    46  0
600 Cold    46  0
650 Cold    46  0
700 Cold    46  0
750 Cold    46  0
800 Cold    46  0
850 Cold    46  2
900 Cold    46  2
950 Cold    46  2
1000    Cold    46  2
1050    Cold    46  4
1100    Cold    46  2
1150    Cold    46  4
1200    Cold    46  4
1250    Cold    46  4
1300    Cold    46  4
0   Cold    47  0
50  Cold    47  0
100 Cold    47  0
150 Cold    47  0
200 Cold    47  0
250 Cold    47  0
300 Cold    47  0
350 Cold    47  0
400 Cold    47  4
450 Cold    47  10
500 Cold    47  16
550 Cold    47  24
600 Cold    47  28
650 Cold    47  36
700 Cold    47  40
750 Cold    47  44
800 Cold    47  48
850 Cold    47  52
900 Cold    47  56
950 Cold    47  60
1000    Cold    47  64
1050    Cold    47  66
1100    Cold    47  70
1150    Cold    47  72
1200    Cold    47  76
1250    Cold    47  78
1300    Cold    47  78
0   Cold    48  0
50  Cold    48  0
100 Cold    48  0
150 Cold    48  0
200 Cold    48  8
250 Cold    48  10
300 Cold    48  18
350 Cold    48  22
400 Cold    48  24
450 Cold    48  30
500 Cold    48  18
550 Cold    48  26
600 Cold    48  34
650 Cold    48  26
700 Cold    48  26
750 Cold    48  30
800 Cold    48  32
850 Cold    48  28
900 Cold    48  30
950 Cold    48  38
1000    Cold    48  18
1050    Cold    48  30
1100    Cold    48  22
1150    Cold    48  26
1200    Cold    48  22
1250    Cold    48  18
1300    Cold    48  28
0   Cold    49  0
50  Cold    49  0
100 Cold    49  0
150 Cold    49  0
200 Cold    49  0
250 Cold    49  0
300 Cold    49  0
350 Cold    49  2
400 Cold    49  6
450 Cold    49  8
500 Cold    49  12
550 Cold    49  18
600 Cold    49  18
650 Cold    49  22
700 Cold    49  24
750 Cold    49  28
800 Cold    49  28
850 Cold    49  30
900 Cold    49  32
950 Cold    49  34
1000    Cold    49  30
1050    Cold    49  42
1100    Cold    49  34
1150    Cold    49  40
1200    Cold    49  34
1250    Cold    49  40
1300    Cold    49  32
0   Cold    50  0
50  Cold    50  0
100 Cold    50  0
150 Cold    50  0
200 Cold    50  0
250 Cold    50  0
300 Cold    50  0
350 Cold    50  4
400 Cold    50  14
450 Cold    50  20
500 Cold    50  28
550 Cold    50  34
600 Cold    50  40
650 Cold    50  46
700 Cold    50  52
750 Cold    50  58
800 Cold    50  64
850 Cold    50  68
900 Cold    50  74
950 Cold    50  78
1000    Cold    50  82
1050    Cold    50  86
1100    Cold    50  92
1150    Cold    50  98
1200    Cold    50  102
1250    Cold    50  104
1300    Cold    50  106
0   Cold    51  0
50  Cold    51  0
100 Cold    51  2
150 Cold    51  8
200 Cold    51  14
250 Cold    51  18
300 Cold    51  22
350 Cold    51  28
400 Cold    51  32
450 Cold    51  36
500 Cold    51  40
550 Cold    51  44
600 Cold    51  48
650 Cold    51  52
700 Cold    51  54
750 Cold    51  58
800 Cold    51  62
850 Cold    51  68
900 Cold    51  72
950 Cold    51  74
1000    Cold    51  78
1050    Cold    51  80
1100    Cold    51  84
1150    Cold    51  88
1200    Cold    51  92
1250    Cold    51  96
1300    Cold    51  98
0   Cold    52  0
50  Cold    52  0
100 Cold    52  0
150 Cold    52  0
200 Cold    52  0
250 Cold    52  0
300 Cold    52  2
350 Cold    52  4
400 Cold    52  8
450 Cold    52  16
500 Cold    52  22
550 Cold    52  32
600 Cold    52  34
650 Cold    52  40
700 Cold    52  40
750 Cold    52  58
800 Cold    52  64
850 Cold    52  72
900 Cold    52  76
950 Cold    52  84
1000    Cold    52  90
1050    Cold    52  96
1100    Cold    52  100
1150    Cold    52  106
1200    Cold    52  112
1250    Cold    52  118
1300    Cold    52  122
0   Cold    53  0
50  Cold    53  0
100 Cold    53  0
150 Cold    53  0
200 Cold    53  2
250 Cold    53  12
300 Cold    53  20
350 Cold    53  26
400 Cold    53  34
450 Cold    53  38
500 Cold    53  44
550 Cold    53  50
600 Cold    53  54
650 Cold    53  60
700 Cold    53  66
750 Cold    53  70
800 Cold    53  72
850 Cold    53  80
900 Cold    53  82
950 Cold    53  88
1000    Cold    53  92
1050    Cold    53  96
1100    Cold    53  100
1150    Cold    53  104
1200    Cold    53  108
1250    Cold    53  112
1300    Cold    53  116
0   Cold    54  0
50  Cold    54  0
100 Cold    54  0
150 Cold    54  0
200 Cold    54  0
250 Cold    54  2
300 Cold    54  8
350 Cold    54  16
400 Cold    54  22
450 Cold    54  24
500 Cold    54  32
550 Cold    54  36
600 Cold    54  36
650 Cold    54  42
700 Cold    54  50
750 Cold    54  56
800 Cold    54  58
850 Cold    54  64
900 Cold    54  66
950 Cold    54  72
1000    Cold    54  74
1050    Cold    54  78
1100    Cold    54  80
1150    Cold    54  84
1200    Cold    54  86
1250    Cold    54  90
1300    Cold    54  94
0   Cold    55  0
50  Cold    55  0
100 Cold    55  0
150 Cold    55  2
200 Cold    55  10
250 Cold    55  18
300 Cold    55  26
350 Cold    55  30
400 Cold    55  38
450 Cold    55  42
500 Cold    55  48
550 Cold    55  52
600 Cold    55  58
650 Cold    55  64
700 Cold    55  68
750 Cold    55  74
800 Cold    55  78
850 Cold    55  84
900 Cold    55  88
950 Cold    55  94
1000    Cold    55  98
1050    Cold    55  100
1100    Cold    55  104
1150    Cold    55  108
1200    Cold    55  110
1250    Cold    55  114
1300    Cold    55  118
0   Cold    56  0
50  Cold    56  0
100 Cold    56  0
150 Cold    56  0
200 Cold    56  0
250 Cold    56  0
300 Cold    56  0
350 Cold    56  8
400 Cold    56  14
450 Cold    56  20
500 Cold    56  24
550 Cold    56  28
600 Cold    56  30
650 Cold    56  36
700 Cold    56  40
750 Cold    56  44
800 Cold    56  46
850 Cold    56  50
900 Cold    56  54
950 Cold    56  58
1000    Cold    56  60
1050    Cold    56  62
1100    Cold    56  66
1150    Cold    56  68
1200    Cold    56  70
1250    Cold    56  72
1300    Cold    56  76
0   Cold    57  0
50  Cold    57  0
100 Cold    57  0
150 Cold    57  0
200 Cold    57  0
250 Cold    57  0
300 Cold    57  0
350 Cold    57  0
400 Cold    57  2
450 Cold    57  10
500 Cold    57  12
550 Cold    57  14
600 Cold    57  16
650 Cold    57  16
700 Cold    57  20
750 Cold    57  20
800 Cold    57  22
850 Cold    57  24
900 Cold    57  26
950 Cold    57  26
1000    Cold    57  28
1050    Cold    57  30
1100    Cold    57  32
1150    Cold    57  32
1200    Cold    57  34
1250    Cold    57  36
1300    Cold    57  36


I tried other options to run the pairwise test by looking at the pairwiseRobustTest() function from the package 'rcompanion' but it is now [Defunct!].
I also checked this post:
Error message in R: error `[.data.frame`(m, labs) : undefined columns selected
but since my data do not have spaces in the column name, I think this solution does not apply.
Also tried to change column names as suggested in: undefined columns selected in plm() function , coxphw undefined columns selected and Undefined columns selected when performing TukeyHSD but the error message persisted.
Also checked column name, as suggested here: undefined columns selected for spearman correlation, but it did not work

You can access rcompanion::pairwiseRobustTest.r here: https://rcompanion.org/r_script_deprecated/pairwiseRobustTest.r.  I don't know that it will do what you want.

The first thing I would try is converting the i variable to a factor in the data frame, so that you don't need as.factor(i) in the formula.

Hello @Sal Mangiafico, thanks for the comment. I converted the i column to factor as in: khg$i <- as.factor(khg$i). This solved the prior error message, but now another one appears: Error in smmcrit(df, ncol(con)) : C must be less than or equal to 28

Hey @SalMangiafico, the function in https://rcompanion.org/r_script_deprecated/pairwiseRobustTest.r worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer from comments:
You can access rcompanion::pairwiseRobustTest.r here: rcompanion.org/r_script_deprecated/pairwiseRobustTest.r
I don't know that it will do what you want, however.
The first thing I would try is converting the i variable to a factor in the data frame, so that you don't need as.factor(i) in the formula.
Different function parse formula differently, so it's possible that the mcp2atm() doesn't parse the as.factor() as expected.
I'm not sure what the Error in smmcrit(df, ncol(con)) : C must be less than or equal to 28 error is about.
Possibly there is an issue with what data are being passed to the function, or it could be a limitation in the function.
